# Yarn - Cannot Resolve Dependency - Core.js

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

I'm trying to run `yarn start` and am getting the following error:

```
  /User/platform/src/containers/App.js: Cannot resolve dependency 'core-js/modules/es6.array.iterator'
```

This is my package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "static-site-mailer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.8.7",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.661.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "1.9.1 - 3",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-modal": "^3.11.2",
    "react-modal-login": "^1.4.5",
    "react-modal-plugin": "^1.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.5",
    "xmlhttprequest": "^1.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.5.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^10.0.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.4.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^3.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^25.4.0",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.13.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.3",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel ./src/index.html",
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "rm -rf dist && parcel build ./src/index.html",
    "watch": "parcel ./src/index.html"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(scss|css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
  }
}
```

What's going on? I assume I am using the incorrect version of one of the packages? I have already uninstalled and reinstalled the packages a few times now but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded **core-js@3.6.5** via **npm** and took a look at the following path:

> core-js/modules

The **modules** directory does NOT contain the file **es6.array.iterator.js** but it DOES contain **es.array.iterator**.

Try changing the path `'core-js/modules/es6.array.iterator.js'` to `'core-js/modules/es.array.iterator.js'` in the affected file.